# Looping over an array of objects and showing values based on static keys defined javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects in my javascript which has data like

```
const data = [
  {
    base: {
      storms: {
        description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Franquia 150€",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },
      fire: {
        description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Sem franquia",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },

      solar: {
        description: "5.000€ | Franquia 150€",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },

      __typename: "HomeBase",
    },
  },
  {....},
  {.....}
];
```

containing various objects inside this array,

so in my file i defined some static keys as

```
export const HOMEPACKAGES = {
  mainInfo : ['base.storms', ///so that when i loop over array above i can use this string to access values for eg - data[i].base.storms
              'base.fire',
              'base.flooding',
              'base.theft'
             ]
}
```

then in order to show the product to the user i am looping over my array of object

```
data.map((item,index)=><div>"Some content here"</div>)
```

now my issue is as soon as i start looping and get my first item from "data" array, how do i grab the value like

> item.base.storms?

i tried it like

```
   data.map((item,index)=>HOMEPACKAGES.mainInfo.map((headerKey,index)=><div>{item.headerKey.included}</div>))   //in order to get item.base.storms.included
```

but got error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: item.headerKey is undefined

Comment: i think item is an object and then "base.storm" is taken as string so thats y i get this issue

Comment: Try item[headerKey].included instead.

Comment: You can access an ObjectKey with an expression by using `[]` brackets. e.g.: `obj[mainInfo[1]] = obj[base.storms] = obj.base.storms`

Comment: @D.Schaller: No, `obj[mainInfo[1]]` would be `obj["base.storms"]`. A string doesn't normally get "deeper" values like that, using `[]` access.

Comment: if i console item, i see my item is

 Object { base: {…}} and headerkey is base.storms

Comment: @Cerbrus Never tried to go deeper, my bad. Usually I don't get in a situation where I would need such a selecting process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function as helper which will loop through the data and keys.

Here I'm using `getData` that till recieve node from `data` array, aswell as  from `HOMEPACKAGES.mainInfo` array. It will spilt the nodes from `HOMEPACKAGES.mainInfo` on `.` and recursively parse the data from `data` array.

```js
const data = [{
  base: {
    storms: {
      description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Franquia 150€",
      included: true,
      __typename: "PackageValue",
    },
    fire: {
      description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Sem franquia",
      included: true,
      __typename: "PackageValue",
    },

    solar: {
      description: "5.000€ | Franquia 150€",
      included: true,
      __typename: "PackageValue",
    },

    __typename: "HomeBase",
  },
}];
const HOMEPACKAGES = {
  mainInfo: ['base.storms', ///so that when i loop over array above i can use this string to access values for eg - data[i].base.storms
    'base.fire',
    'base.flooding',
    'base.theft'
  ]
}
function getData(key, item) {
  const keys = key.split('.');
  let respData = item;
  keys.forEach((node) => respData = respData[node]);      
  return respData;
}
const resp = data.map((item,index) => HOMEPACKAGES.mainInfo.map((headerKey,index)=>{
  return getData(headerKey, item)
}))   //in order to get item.base.storms.included  
console.log(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate `base.storms` and feed in into the object field in order:

```js
const data = [
  {
    base: {
      storms: {
        description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Franquia 150€",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },
      fire: {
        description: "Edíficio 100.000€ | Conteúdo 50.000€ | Sem franquia",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },

      solar: {
        description: "5.000€ | Franquia 150€",
        included: true,
        __typename: "PackageValue",
      },

      __typename: "HomeBase",
    },
  },
];

const statics = {
  mainInfo: [
    'base.storms',
    'base.fire',
    'base.flooding',
    'base.theft'
  ]
}

const storms = data.map(el => {
  const stormsInfo = statics.mainInfo[0].split('.')
  return el[stormsInfo[0]][stormsInfo[1]]
})

console.log(storms)
```

Comment: Okay, but what if the string in `mainInfo` contains 2 or even more periods?

Comment: I doubt the object will be so nested that accessing indices 0,1,2 is gonna be unreasonable. Of course there are more general solutions _with a lot more code_, I thought that this will be just enough for OP.

Comment: A generic getter function really isn't that complex... Nitheesh's answer contains one that's only 4 lines of code.

Comment: Sure, it is a good answer :)